# Confusion - implemented Interface needs casting?

Tags: .net, vb.net, collections, interface

I have an Entity class which Implements IWeightable:

```
Public Interface IWeightable

    Property WeightState As WeightState

End Interface
```

I have a WeightCalculator class:

```
Public Class WeightsCalculator

    Public Sub New(...)
        ...
    End Sub

    Public Sub Calculate(ByVal entites As IList(Of IWeightable))
        ...
    End Sub

End Class
```

Following the process:

1. Instantiate collection of Entity
   `Dim entites As New List(Of Entity)`
2. Instantiate WeightsCalculator `Dim
   wc As New WeightsCalculator(...)`

Why can I not do wc.Calculate(entities)? I receive:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[mynameSpace.Entity]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[myNamespace.IWeightable]'.

If Entity implements IWeightable why is this not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn’t work.

Assume you have a different class, `OtherEntity`, that would also implement the interface. If your above code would work, the method `Calculate` could add an instance of `OtherEntity` to your list of `Entity`:

```
Dim entities As New List(Of Entity)()
Dim weightables As List(Of IWeightable) = entities ' VB forbids this assignment!
weightables.Add(New OtherEntity())
```

That is illegal. If it weren’t, what would the content of `entities(0)` be?

To make the code work, use a generic method with a constraint instead:

```
Public Sub Calculate(Of T As IWeightable)(ByVal entites As IList(Of T))
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, I knew I was being naive. I will implement the generic method.

Answer (score 6):

A `List(Of Entity)` isn't an `IList(Of IWeightable)`. Consider this code (where `OtherWeightable` implements `IWeightable`):

```
Dim list As IList(Of IWeightable) = New List(Of Entity)
list.Add(new OtherWeightable)
```

The second line as to compile - there's nothing suspicious about it - but you don't want an `OtherWeightable` element in a `List(Of Entity)`.

.NET 4 has a *partial* solution to this in the form of *generic variance*. If your `Calculate` method only iterates over `entities`, you could change the signature to this:

```
Public Sub Calculate(ByVal entites As IEnumerable(Of IWeightable))
```

Although `IList(Of T)` is *invariant*, `IEnumerable(Of T)` is *covariant* in `T`, because the API only ever allows values of type `T` to be *returned* by it - there are no parameters of type `T` in methods of `IEnumerable(Of T)`. So there's a conversion from `List(Entity)` to `IEnumerable(Of IWeightable)`.

Generic variance is a hairy topic - at NDC 2010 I gave a presentation on it which you may find useful. You can watch it at the [NDC 2010 videos page](http://streaming.ndc2010.no/tcs/). (Search for "variance.")

If you're using .NET 3.5 or earlier, Konrad's suggestion of making `Calculate` generic is a fine choice.

Comment: I appreciate the time spent on the response - it is a great help.